# Upload File With a Caption

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

How can I upload multiple files with its own caption?
I gave no problem to upload multiple files, but i have no idea on how to put the caption (as I am going to display the uploaded images in next page (report)).

Can you help me?

Comment: Is this just a form-design question? The only answer I can think there is to your question is to have a text input per file input into which the user types the caption. But that sounds so obvious that perhaps I'm misreading you, or your question is a bit vague.  What's the *actual* specific problem you're having? What's blocking you from progressing? I also think "Oracle" is probably irrelevant to this question. What's that got to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the parameter       cffile.clientFile for displaying that